# Search Google Shopping products PHP

Tags: php, ajax, google-api, google-shopping-api

Is it possible, using Google's API or merely faking a request to retrieve the products from a google shopping search query ? For example :

https://www.google.de/#tbm=shop&q=Samsung+Galaxy

I would like to retrieve all the results for the following query, trying to fake a request resulted me in an empty page as it seems like it makes a weird AJAX request to Google's API which I cannot parse.
Is there something similar to

http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&q=Samsung+Galaxy
for example ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing a wide research I've seen that there is no API for google shopping - they closed it a while ago.

Therefore I used PhantomJS to render the whole page and then retrieve the data.